# Is React state property set to undefined during a change?

Tags: reactjs

I've got this state set as a default:

```
this.state = {
  topic: ' ',
  questions: [],
  answers: [[' ']],
  types: [' '],
};
```

Then I set an AJAX call, and organize everything so it's filled then.

```
loadBody() {
 axios.get(`/api/getSurveyBody/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
  .then((result) => {
    this.loadQuestions(result.data);
    this.loadAnswers(result.data);
    this.loadTypes(result.data);
  })
  .then((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

loadAnswers(array) {
   const answers = array.map(element => ([
     element.answer1,
     element.answer2,
     element.answer3,
     element.answer4,
    ]));
   this.setState({ answers });
}
```

Later I pass this values and read them in another component like that:

```
{questions.map((element, index, array) => (
  <div className="question" key={keyIndex(array, index)[index].id}>
    <h3>
      {element}
    </h3>
    { answers[index] } //Here is console.log() showed on the image
  </div>
))}
```

The problem with this, is that I've got an error that answers is undefined, despite its default value already set. I logged it and saw this:

[image]

Which is almost correct, first log should be default as it is, second should be this four clear strings, and third this four sentences. I wonder why it looks like `answers` array is suddenly set to undefined despite its default value?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't, but if you're looking to not throw an error, you can use a fallback value for `questions`. Something else in your code isn't working then. Trace the entire data flow that leads to `questions` and you might get your answer

```
(questions || []).map
```

Comment: It's indeed a good idea to implement this fallback, so thanks. Although It doesn't solve my problem. It's not that `questions` array is invalid, it's that `answers` is suddenly undefined.

Comment: @SlawekWozniak What does your ajax call look like and how are you adding that response data to your component's state?

Comment: I'll put this in the question

Comment: @SlawekWozniak console log the first line of `loadAnswers` and check what `result` is in `loadBody` and see if it's what you expect

Comment: I did, and everything is alright, it's called exactly once and result is correct.

Comment: @SlawekWozniak My next thought would be `answers[index]`. `questions`. Are you sure `answers` is an array that's long enough to keep having `index` be an actual value in the array?

Comment: Oh that's a good question! I checked this and it looks like  `answers` property is loaded a little bit later than `questions`. Therefore in `answers`, there's no a `[1]` index, which returns undefined. You think I should use callbacks in setState method?

Comment: @SlawekWozniak Do both at once in a single `setState`. `this.setState({ answers, questions })` You'll have to modify your code a little to do this

Comment: Always happy to help. Happy coding

Comment: Thanks, should I upvote and accept as an answer if it was in comments?